# Black folder icons in Windows 8 when try open files by Visual Studio

Tags: windows, windows-8, icons, visual-studio-2012

When I try to open a file from within  Visual Studio or SQL Management Studio, within the browser dialog, all the icons are black as per the screen shots below.

[image]

When I right click and go to properties of any folder I got:

[image]

However, when I open a file from Word or Paint, within the browser dialog the icons show as normal.

The icons in File Explorer looks ok as well.
[image]
Any idea what's the problem is?

Comment: `lately I have problem with folder icons when I try to open some file by Visual Studio or SQL Management Studio.` - It looks like it is affecting all folders?

Comment: Yes, all folders.

Comment: So, why did you write only files by Visual Studio and SSMS? Please [click here to edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/753394/edit) and make sure it is clear :)

Comment: Sorry,I mean that all folders are black, when I try open some files by Paint or Word folders look ok.

Comment: Good edit, I can see what you mean now. +1

Comment: heh, Problem solved :) I needed to uninstall one plugin for Visual Studio ...  : )

Comment: You can answer your own question

Comment: @user322797 which plugin have you removed to fix it?

Comment: "file nesting" plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved problem by uninstalling "file nesting" extension for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, what I did was I deleted all the `iconcache` and `thumbcache` files used by File Explorer to cache the icons.

The location for the iconcache and thumbcache different from Windows 7. I am on Windows 10 CTP, but I believe it is the same with Windows 8 or 8.1. For Windows 10 CTP it is at:

`C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`

You will need to start an elevated command prompt and delete it from the command line. Before you delete the files, kill `Windows Explorer` process using Task Manager first.

Then delete all `thumbcache*` and `iconcache*`, restart your computer afterward. The cache will be re-created upon restart.